# How do I find the partition key of Cassandra partitions with size greater than 100MB?

Tags: cassandra, nosql, cassandra-3.0

I want to get a list of partition with size greater than 100 MB for analysis. How do I achieve this ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems. I have cast a vote to have your post moved to dba.stackexchange.com instead. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cassandra logs a `WARN` with details of partitions getting compacted when the partition size is larger than `compaction_large_partition_warning_threshold`. The default in `cassandra.yaml` is 100MB:

```
# Log a warning when compacting partitions larger than this value
compaction_large_partition_warning_threshold: 100MiB
```

You can parse the `system.log` on the Cassandra nodes and look for log entries which contain the string `Writing large partition`. It looks something like:

```
WARN  [CompactionExecutor:#] BigTableWriter.java:258 maybeLogLargePartitionWarning \
  Writing large partition ks_name/tbl_name:pk (###.###MiB) to sstable /path/to/.../...-big-Data.db
```

It should be easy enough to write a shell script that would extract the table name and partition key from the logs. Cheers!